# Minimizing the $L^2$ error when approximating with trigonometric polynomials

Tags: approximation

I want to find approximations ${\rm g}_{n}\left(x\right) \in T_{n}$ of
$\,\,{\rm f}\left(x\right)$, so that the error
$$
\left\vert\left\vert\,{\rm f} - {\rm g}_{n}\,\right\vert\right\vert^{2}
=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\left[{\rm f}\left(x\right) - {\rm g}_{n}\left(x\right)\right]^{2}\,{\rm d}x
$$
is minimal.

How to do that?

Here are my $f(x)$ functions:

a) $f(x) = x$,

b) $f(x) = (x-\pi)^2$

c) $f(x) =e^x$

d) $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l l}
        1, & 0 \leq x \leq \pi,
        \\
        0, & \pi < x \leq 2 \pi.
    \end{array} \right.$

Thank you very much guys =)

PS: $T_n$ is the vector space of the trigonometric polynomials with size $\leq n$

Comment: Instead of "fault" or "mistake", I think you mean "error".

Comment: Yeah okay, sry english is not my native language

Comment: No problem :)  I edited your title to try to get your question some more views.

Comment: Have you really not covered the theorem of optimal approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of all the $n^{th}$ degree trigonometric polynomials, the $n^{th}$ partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$ best approximates $f$. To put it mathematically,

$\|f-s_n\| \leq \|f-p\| \, \, \, \ s_n, p \in T_n$

So just find the Fourier coefficients if the given functions in $[0, 2\pi]$ and you have your answer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Least_squares_property

$$
s_n = a_0 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k\cos kx + b_k \sin kx \\
a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}f \ \mathrm{d}x \\
a_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}f\cos kx \ \mathrm{d}x \\
b_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}f \sin kx \ \mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: How to calculate the Fourier coefficients ? I thought i need supportive points to calculate this, or not? SRY i dont really get it. But Thanks!!

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Amazing, so i just insert the funktions instead of $f$ and calculate $a_0, a_k, b_k$ and then i have my $s_n$. Now i have to calculate the $n^{th}$ partial sum of $s_n$ ? and this is my answer?

Comment: Exactly, that's all you need to do.

Comment: Okay, again thank you very much. =)